# PHP: "Callback server" for a Windows server?

Tags: php, windows, callback, scheduled-tasks

I am programming PHP applications where I need to move processing routines from the client (browser) to the server. We have our own dedicated Windows servers.

Let us say that a shopper buys something and the system has to generate a nice and complex invoice PDF (and do a lot other things that takes some seconds) and after this send it to the client as fast as possible. Right now, I have running these time-consuming routines in a hidden Iframe and hoping that client is not breaking the routine by going to another page. It is not a good solution.

A much better solution would be to trigger some kind of software on the Windows server that does the processing instead of the browser (and does it instantly).

I could use "Scheduled Tasks" in Windows but the quickest it can run is each minute. I need something that can run instantly. Do you know what can do this on a Windows server? Like some kind callback server (software).

Comment: To make sure user navigation doesn't stop your scripting you can use `ignore_user_abort(true);`. As you are saying this process is time taking 

You can create a background process . Search more about this on google

Comment: Hi Akash :-) Thank so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure user navigation doesn't stop your scripting you can use `ignore_user_abort(true);`

You can also use `exec` create background process and run your php script

> Example

```
exec("start /B php Notify.php");
```

To learn more about `exec`function click [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

You can find more information by googling stuffs.